# Finding a majorant without quadratic exponent

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about finding a majorant for a function where one of the exponents is not quadratic. Is there a general solution for those type of problems?

let$\  f_t = e^{-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}{3t}+ikx} $

I need to find a majorant $g\ $ such that $ \forall t: \left|f_t\right| \le g$ and $\int g < \infty$

Comment: Are you trying to use a domination theorem ?

Comment: Yes, dominated convergence, I know that when taking the absolute value of f_t the ikx part is 1, but i can't solve the rest.

Comment: What do you want to show ? Sometimes you only need to dominate on every segment of $\mathbb{R}$, which is much easier than dominating on all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I want to calculate $lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^{\infty} f_t dx$

Comment: So you are only concerned with $t > M$ for some $M$, not with all $t$, and $x > t$, not all $x$. That is a different matter.  For $t < 0, f_t \notin L^1(\Bbb R)$. And $f_0$ is not even defined. But for $t > 0, f_t \in L^1([t, \infty))$.